# Log4j ignored in a service inherited from some class

Tags: grails, service, annotations, log4j

In my Grails 2.2.4 app I have a service (default package):

```
@Log4j
class ReceiverService extends ReceiverAdapter {

  static transactional = false

  def someMethod(){
    log.info "aaaaa"
  }   

}
```

in my Config.groovy:

```
log4j = {

  environments {
    development{
      info stdout:'grails.app.controllers'
      debug stdout:[
        'grails.app.services'
      ]
    }
```

I never see logs coming from this service. Other services and controllers, which do not extend any other class are logging as desired. It seems to me, that the `@Log4j` annotation are ignored, and the rules in Config.groovy are not applied to them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any special reason for explicitly using `@Log4j`?

Comment: it looks like, if I extend a non-service class, the grails doesn't inject the `log` property. I was getting `MissingPropertyExc`

Comment: I've had mixed success with the injected logger when extending classes. Sometimes I've had to revert to instantiating my own logger.